# how to use integer in java enum

Tags: java, enums

Is there any way to keep straight integer in Java Enum ?

example: i am working on a Restaurant management system. i want to know what quantity of unit of any food a customer will order (e.g 1,2,5 etc.)

so i added a combo box in my GUI where list of units will be shown as : 1, 2, 3 etc. Now, Java Enum does not allowing me to write the code like this:

```
   public enum UnitEnum {
      1,2,3,4,5;
   }
```

What least i can do is writing it as:

```
   public enum UnitEnum {
      _1,_2,_3,_4,_5;
   }
```

but it is very much odd looking. Is there any way to make it look like the first one ? ( where there is no under score ).

Comment: No, there is not. Names must start with eiter a character, a `$` or an `_`. The question is: why not write them: `ONE`, `TWO`,...?

Comment: it's just for saving time :p see, one, two, three etc. takes so many letters to type.

Comment: Do you have to use an an enum?  Why not `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5)))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
public enum UnitEnum {
  ONE(1),
  TWO(2),
  THREE(3),
  FOUR(4),
  FIVE(5);

  public final int quantity;

  UnitEnum(int q) {
     this.quantity = q;
  }

  public int getQuantity() { return this.quantity; }
}
```

Comment: And display the quantity in the combobox. `private UnitEnum(int q) { quantity = q; }` you assumed trivial.

Comment: i appreciate.

it says constructor UnitEnum in enum UnitEnum cannot be applied to given types.

required: no argument
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

Comment: Why not using `ordinal()` here instead of defining the field `quantity`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an little [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) about [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

The way I would choose for your Problem is something like:

```
//Your enum
public enum UnitEnum{ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE};
//Using your enum
myENUM = 1; //compilation error  
myENUM = UnitEnum.ONE // works
```

Answer (score 0):

`enum CheeseNuggets { X6, X9 }`?  Maybe not use an enum, but a class wrapping `int[]`.

```
public class Ints {
    public final int[] values;

    public Ints(int... values) {
        this.values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    }
}
```